# rotate pattern fill in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns, perspective

Is it possible to rotate a pattern fill in photoshop? I need to make a maze for a project, but I can't rotate a pattern to have the right perspective.

I found the vanishing point in Photoshop, but I can't seem to get it working, even with some tutorials found on the web.

When I go to Edit > Transform Path, I can rotate it, but not the right amount of degrees.

I included a screenshot of my work, hopefully it helps to understand my question.
[image: Maze]
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: could you please upload the source file.

Comment: Unfortunately, pattern *fills* can not be transformed or adjusted to any real degree. They absolutely can not be rotated (that feature has been requested). You'll have to flatten the pattern fill to a layer, then transform that layer.

Comment: @Scott - thanks for your advice, I'll try you tip tomorrow.

Comment: @hsawires - I'm not behind my mac right now, so i'm not able to upload the source file at this moment.

Comment: @Jules .. what I want to try is the [The Vanishing tool] where I can vanish the pattern using the stamp tool.

Comment: @hsawires here is a link to dropbox where the source file is located: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xs7y80ik31o6as/Maze_Bicymple.psd?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to rotate, as that wouldn't give the correct perspective.

Instead, create a rectangle about the size of the wall if it wasn't distorted, then apply the pattern to that.

In the layers panel, completely rasterize the new rectangle.

Go to Edit>Transform>Perspective to correctly distort the image, and place it in the right spot.

Comment: I think I have to convert the layer to a smart object? Only then I'm able to rasterize the layer

Answer (score 0):

Once you've applied your pattern, right-click on said layer, then create layer, this will put any and all effects on their own layer, then just select the pattern layer and rotate it as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the middle of a dead line so I had to find a quick way around this!
Rotate the canvas instead of the pattern, then apply the pattern and rotate back. Might not be the best way but it works!